# Periodic task on user using Celery or iterate all users with Celery Beat

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, celerybeat

I want to perform certain operations on the Django "User" model once the last time since logging in is more than 60 days. I want to know what is the best practice for these kinds of operations.

I thought of the following:

1- when the user logs in I start a Celery task that activates after 60 days to do the operation

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
send_date = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=60)
email_user.apply_async([user], eta=send_date)
```

2- set up a Celery Beat task that runs everyday at a certain time and iterate over all the users in the database to check every user's last login time and if the last login time is > 60 the perform the operation

```py
users = User.objects.all()
for user in users:
    if (user.last_login + timedelta(days=60)) < datetime.utcnow():
        email_user(user)
```

first method would cause too many tasks to be open at the same time and I don't know what would happen in case of system failures will the tasks remain or not? 
and the second method would iterate all the users in the DB everyday but it will be only 1 task

I am not sure which way is the best or if there is a 3rd better way.

Comment: Method #2 is much much better. You can also use User.objects.filter(last_login__lte=datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(60)) to pre-filter and remove the if statement. Method #1 also has major issues with managing code changes, deployments, and making changes to the 60 day time window.

Comment: Method #2 is preferred. But also depends on what is the size of your user table?

Comment: the user table is expected to grow over time, it is a publicly accessible website.